# How to automatically Increase the height of Materialize Slider as per the content inside it?

Tags: html, css

I am using the Materialize framework in a project and using its slider. But I have not found the way of automatically increase the height of the slider as per the content (text) inside it. Is there any way to do this.

I have a different amount of text for each slider, so I can't fix the height of a slider to a specific height. Some slider has fewer data & some slider has more data, so fixing the height of the entire slider is not going to work for me. Please find out a solution for me.

HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="carousel carousel-slider center">
            <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
               <h2>First Slider</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore quod, amet eius reprehenderit vel dignissimos explicabo. Et aperiam, veniam saepe facilis ad amet quas alias deserunt provident laboriosam. Temporibus, illum?</p>         
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
              <h2>Second Slider</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, maxime, repellat! Animi necessitatibus obcaecati dicta cum eligendi, dolorem accusantium omnis. In aut dolor eum laudantium porro libero, nam? Laudantium nulla repudiandae, unde explicabo adipisci. Adipisci, non doloribus quas quasi. Doloremque!  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
              <h2>Third Slider</h2>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloremque eos maiores vel cupiditate labore optio quibusdam iusto possimus eum veritatis maxime quam illum necessitatibus dignissimos eaque, magnam, commodi. Perspiciatis fuga labore temporibus. Voluptate consequatur optio, dolores nam totam velit. Qui fugiat explicabo blanditiis iure nisi fuga distinctio quis eos! Perspiciatis inventore, ab tenetur! Ratione voluptatibus error ex, earum neque eos.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
              <h2>Fourth Slider</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Exercitationem placeat qui, quae itaque enim. Perferendis ea molestias quod consectetur qui distinctio vel quisquam quasi, doloribus fugiat hic iure, ad harum ex, saepe, dignissimos itaque accusantium veniam reprehenderit esse voluptatem quae? Sunt harum porro soluta provident, laudantium ab debitis amet alias sed. Quas recusandae iusto aperiam amet exercitationem et, ex iure molestias, id. Dignissimos voluptates, quam repellendus earum, repudiandae nisi adipisci veritatis quos similique vitae dolorem nam enim delectus, facilis dolores eveniet sequi neque, praesentium sapiente quidem temporibus? Delectus, a provident laudantium, enim ea at quo quae, est, accusamus minus sequi?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.carousel.carousel-slider{
      height: 200px !important;
    }
```

If I fix the height 200px for the slider, then it will not work for the next slider because the next slider contains more text than the previous. So, what is the solution that the slider gets the automatic height according to the content inside it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are setting the slider as a constant 200px. Try setting the height as:

```
height: auto;
```

or

```
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Sorry! Nick...It does not work. I have already tried to set height as "auto" and "100%", but the entire slider gets no height. It is because the child class "carousel-item" has the position "absolute".

Comment: Have you tried adding a max-height and a min height? Like this: `min-height: 200px;` `max-height:500px`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. But min-height or max-height only works for a particular slider. If I set min-height to something like 200px, then it will not work for the other slider which has more text, so in this situation, the bottom text of other slider gets hidden due to less height. And if I set the max-height to 500px, it will not look good for the slider which has less data because there comes a huge gap at the bottom below the text. Is there any way that the slider automatically gets the height according to the data inside it...?

Comment: hmm. It looked at the materialize docs and there is only an option to make the sliders width max. What you should probably do in this situation is target each individual slider and set the height accordingly. You can do this by adding `slide-one` to your carousel items and then in css do: `.carousel.carousel-slider.slide-one{ height: 200px !important;}` and rinse and repeat for all your slides. It's not a very clean way but it looks to be the best solution

Comment: Yes, Nick. This will work. I really appreciate your replies & the efforts that you made for me. But I was looking for a prominent way to solve this problem because I want to make this design responsive to the mobile also. In this case, I will have to set a different height for the mobile view also. Sometimes, the client may increase or decrease the quantity of data for any of the sliders, then it will be needed to change the height of the slider again otherwise the design will look clumsy.

Comment: Ah your in a tough situation. This may take some extra time but you can use swiperjs. I've used it before and I think it will solve the problem of resizing the slider. https://swiperjs.com/